# Querying list of Map in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have one sample json as below

```json
[
    {
        "City1":
            [ 
                { "Name" : "XPerson",
                "Age"  : 18},
                { "Name" : "YPerson",
                "Age"  : 18}
            ],
        "PinCode":314001
    },
    {
        "City2":
            [ 
                { "Name" : "APerson",
                  "Age"  : 25},
                { "Name" : "ZPerson",
                "Age"  : 26}
            ],
        "PinCode":314002
    }
]
```

I can have this list to N numbers. I want to separate this in different column based on Age like less than 18 in column1, between 18 to 25 in column2 and all other in column3. It should be based on City which means against city 1 only available person should be shown?

How can we achieve in postgres?

Answer (score 0):

```
with invars as (
  select '[
    {
        "City1":
            [ 
                { "Name" : "XPerson",
                "Age"  : 18},
                { "Name" : "YPerson",
                "Age"  : 18}
            ],
        "PinCode":314001
    },
    {
        "City2":
            [ 
                { "Name" : "APerson",
                  "Age"  : 25},
                { "Name" : "ZPerson",
                "Age"  : 26}
            ],
        "PinCode":314002
    }
]'::jsonb as j
), blowout as (
  select o.k, (e2.el->>'Age')::int as age
    from invars 
         cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(j) as e(el)
         cross join lateral jsonb_each(el) as o(k, v)
         join lateral jsonb_array_elements(v) as e2(el)
           on jsonb_typeof(v) = 'array'
)
select k as city, 
       count(*) filter (where age < 18) as less_than_18,
       count(*) filter (where age between 18 and 25) as between_18_and_25,
       count(*) filter (where age > 25) as other
  from blowout
 group by k;
```